# Set page number of report programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

How can I set the page number when viewing a Crystal Report? I tried:

```
crystalReportsViewer.ViewerCore.CurrentPageNumber = result;
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: Right click on report  -- > insert--> Special Field - > Page N of M and drag it where you want to show on report

Comment: that's no solution for me, becaue i can't change the look of the cr controls

Comment: ok got it: crystalReportsViewer.ViewerCore.ShowNthPage(Result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the [ShowNthPage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa665031(v=vs.71).aspx) function.

```
crystalReportsViewer.ViewerCore.ShowNthPage(result);
```

This assumes the number of page you wish to display is either constant or calculable. If the desired page gets pushed up or down due to added/removed records, you'll need to take that into account somehow.